# Redirect pipes of parent process without affecting child process

Tags: python, c++, gdb, pipe

I am running a third-party python script which launches `gdb` with my `cpp` executable. I believe the script launches `gdb` as a child process. I would like to disable or redirect the output from the python script while keeping the output from `gdb`.

Is there anyway to do this from the command line? When I pipe the script into `/dev/null`, even the `gdb` output is removed.

Modifying the python script is an option, but one I'd rather avoid as it's not very portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to disable or redirect the output from the python script
>   while keeping the output from `gdb`.

In this particular case you can save gdb output to a file (by default to `gdb.txt`).

```
gdb$ set logging on
Copying output to gdb.txt.
gdb$
```

You can add this command to `.gdbinit` - gdb initialization script. This allows you not to modify python script. Than you can pipe python script output to `/dev/null` while gdb output will be saved to a file (`gdb.txt` by default).